# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymsgbox

Tags: python, python-3.10

```
   Collecting PyAutoGUI
   Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.53-py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting python3-Xlib
   Using cached python3_xlib-0.15-py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting mouseinfo
   Using cached MouseInfo-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21
   Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.28.tar.gz (25 kB)
   Installing build dependencies ... done
   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
   Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5
   Using cached PyGetWindow-0.0.9-py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting pymsgbox
   Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)
   Installing build dependencies ... done
   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
   Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1
   Using cached pytweening-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting pyrect
   Using cached PyRect-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mouseinfo->PyAutoGUI) (1.8.2)
   Building wheels for collected packages: pyscreeze, pymsgbox
   Building wheel for pyscreeze (pyproject.toml) ... error
   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

   × Building wheel for pyscreeze (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.

    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/_distutils_system_mod.py", line 137, in wrapped_load_schemes
      _inject_headers(name, scheme)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/_distutils_system_mod.py", line 125, in _inject_headers
      scheme['headers'] = orig_install._load_schemes()['posix_prefix']['headers']
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/_distutils_system_mod.py", line 135, in wrapped_load_schemes
      schemes = _load_schemes()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 103, in _load_schemes
      sysconfig_schemes = _load_sysconfig_schemes() or {}
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 91, in _load_sysconfig_schemes
      with contextlib.suppress(AttributeError):
  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
  [end of output]
```

*note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.*

**ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymsgbox
Failed to build pyscreeze pymsgbox

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscreeze, pymsgbox, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**

Comment: A number of us are having the same problem building wheels for anything with python3.10. Are you using Debian testing/unstable? Because at least in that context a bug report which seems to cover your case is filed here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1010284. An unadvised, but possibly effective, workaround hack is stated here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11070#issuecomment-1113245191.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on my Kali Linux while installing pyautogui. It happens when you have an apt installation pending or when installation fails or some other apt-get error. To fix this just run

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now try installing pyautogui again...

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround would be to work on a venv:

```
    python -m venv .venv source .venv/bin/activate pip install ...
```

which works for me.

Comment: This is showing. Error: Unable to create directory '/home/.../.venv/bin/activate'

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m venv .venv source .venv/bin/activate pip install....

apt install python3.10-venv
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.